# Persistence Storage solution for docker swarm

Tags: docker, containers, persistence, docker-swarm

we have a 5 node docker swarm cluster with three managers and 2 workers. These are all Virtual machines running in private local enrionment. need to setup shared storage for the docker swarm.

we are looking at glusterfs, nfs as a storage solution for swarm.
need pointers and help on setting up the storage solution. please help

Comment: Are you on the cloud (i.e. AWS or Azure) or On-prem?

Comment: What kind of services are going to use the shared storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docker swarm was setup on Azure cloud. We have installed azure storage driver plugin on each of the nodes. with storage account name and access key we are able to mount azure file storage to containers in swarm